# Accessing HTML DOM Object from WINRT Webview control

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I have found how to load the local html page in Webview XAML Control

Visit [winrt: load local html and its resources in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521884/winrt-load-local-html-and-its-resources-in-webview)

What i am unable to find is how to access the HTML DOM Object of the Webview Control

I am developing a C# metro style windows 8 application,i want to capture the user signature,since there is no control yet in winrt xaml for that,i am trying to do that using JQUERY

My SignatureCpture is loaded in the webView,after the user has finished signing i need to read the signature,for which i have to access the HTML DOM of the WebView

I have some hidden field in the  Page,i need to use document.getElementByID('') to get the value and store it in database

Answer (score 1):

please refer to this sample code in MSDN Code Gallery: [XAML WebView control Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7). In the 5th scenario, it demonstrates how to access the html dom.